# Modal only triggered after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two questions about this code. The first is why the modal is not shown before the alert? The second is how can i delay the modal, because the popup is so fast that i can't see nothing in the modal.

```
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        //$('#myModal').delay(5000).modal('hide'); does not work

    });


    $(".generate_report").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.post("xls.php", $(".form_report").serialize(), function() {
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert("should be executed only after modal");
        });
    });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1495uy71/1/)

Comment: for the delay you can use setTimeout()

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with this code:

```
$(".generate_report").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $.post("xls.php", $(".form_report").serialize(),function(data){
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            alert("after modal");

        }) 
    }, 2000);
});
```

**And remove this code**

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    //$('#myModal').delay(5000).modal('hide'); does not work

});
```

Comment: i can't remove the code, because the loading should be generic to any ajax request.

Comment: well apparently just add sleep(1) in PHP will solve all issues. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What this code does is show a modal when the ajax call starts and instantly hide it when its done. You can use a timer to wait a while before closing it.

Also you've nested a callback function in your jQuery.post, but you don't use it which causes confusing code here. Theres no need to use .done() when you're just going to append it to the AJAX function directly. You can just use the callback function here.

```
$.post("xls.php", $(".form_report").serialize(), function(data) {            
    alert("should be executed only after modal");
});
```

But that is just a code styling concern. The done(), success(), fail() methods are used on a jQuery.Deferred promise object, which $.ajax happens to return. And since $.post/$.get are just pointers to $.ajax, they will too.

Secondly, if you want the modal to wait before it closes, you can do this:

```
var waitTimer;
var timeToWait = 2000; // Time to wait here
var $myModal = $('#myModal');
$myModal.modal('hide');

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $myModal.modal('show');
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    if (waitTimer) {
       clearTimeout(waitTimer);
    }

    waitTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $myModal.modal('hide');
    }, msToWait);
});
```

The .delay() method you tried to use only works after you've animated something.

Also a quick tip: Cache your jQuery selectors. You're telling jQuery to jump in the DOM 3 times to search for the same element.